# how do i generate multiple tag based on comma separated value from single tag in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

Given input as XML:

`<root>`
         `<article>`test1,test2,test3`</article>`
`</root>`

and now need XSLT logic to generate output XML as

`<article>test1</article>
 <article>test2</article>
 <article>test3</article>`

Comment: With XSLT questions, please always say whether you have any constraints regarding the version of XSLT that you can use. Otherwise anyone answering risks wasting their time. Use the question tags such as "xslt 1.0" and "xslt 2.0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you need to `tokenize` the contents of the `article` element(s) and create a new `article` element for each token with `xsl:element`, in XSLT 3 one way to achieve that is with

```
  <xsl:template match="article">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tokenize(., ',')">
          <xsl:with-param name="element-name" select="node-name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]">
      <xsl:param name="element-name"/>
      <xsl:element name="{$element-name}">{.}</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Minimal but complete sample would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="article">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tokenize(., ',')">
          <xsl:with-param name="element-name" select="node-name()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]">
      <xsl:param name="element-name"/>
      <xsl:element name="{$element-name}">{.}</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHU8

Comment: Hey Martin, Is it possible to do the changes for XSLT version 1.0
as i can see on above answer, this one is implemented for version 3.0

Comment: I am sure there are already lots of answers to similar questions done with XSLT 1 or 2, I only bothered to answer that old question again to show a slightly different approach possible in XSLT 3 by pushing the result of `tokenize` directly to a template. But `tokenize` exists in XSLT 2 as well and as an EXSLT (http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) extension in XSLT 1 (http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/str.tokenize.template.xsl) so look at existing answers.